# Failed loading php_xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to configure PhpStorm. Actually I'm installing Xdebug, but when I load the `php.exe`, PhpStorm says "debugger not installed", as if it doesn't see it, but it's there!

My PHP version is `7.3.11`, so I download `xdebug-2.8`

In the prompt, writing `php -v` I get this:

> Failed loading C:\php7\php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
>   PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2019 11:20:18) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )

I removed the Visual C++ 2017 redistributable and install 2015 version, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try installing the Thread Safe Version (TS) and not (NTS)

Comment: it is the safe version

Comment: No.... Read the message `C:\php7\php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.3-vc15->>>>nts<<<<-x86_64.dll`

Comment: ah yeah! you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out which exact file to download, please use the [wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard). This will direct you towards the correct variant of the Xdebug DLL.

Comment: This worked well :-)